# The message of jquery validation "required(dependency-callback)" not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

The jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hbrls/Snn87/12/

I have a verify code field: `<input type="text" id="verfy_code" name="verfy_code" class="required" />`

and the validation js is:

```
    $("#aspnetForm").validate({
            rules: {
                verfy_code: {
                    required: function(element) { return check_verfy_code(); }
                }
            },
            messages: {
                verfy_code: { required: "verify code not correct" }
            }
        });
    function check_verfy_code() {
        var flag = false;
        //some ajax to check if verfy_code equalto session["verfy_code"]
        //I've not implemented this, so this function will always return false
        return flag;
    }
```

The messages never show.

Comment: can you set this up in [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net), so that it'll be easier for us to give a try?

Comment: @Vikas Good idea. But I'm not familiar with jsFiddle. Now nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation for the `required(dependency-callback)` option:

> The function is executed with the element as it's only argument: **If it
>   returns true, the element is required.**

You are always returning `false`, therefore the element is *never* required.

If you return `true` from your function your dependency callback will work as you expect:

```
function check_verfy_code() {
    var flag = true;
    //some ajax to check if verfy_code equalto session["verfy_code"]
    //I've not implemented this, so this function will always return false
    return flag;
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jZjFq/